# how to call C# from c++

Tags: c#, c++

I am wondering what's the way to call a c# class method from C++(Native, not C++ CLI) code? Need simple and elegant way

Comment: As cool as it may be the thought hurts

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling C# code from C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778590/calling-c-sharp-code-from-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turn your C# assembly into a COM visible one and use COM interfaces. That is the only way to make it work beside self made IPC as far as I know. The problem comes from the .NET environment under which the .NET assembly must run and C++ runs under its native C++ environment.

The only way of communicating is either an IPC mechanism (sockets, ...) or use COM, as the processes have to be "decoupled".

Here is a tutorial for the COM based solution:

- [MSDN - COM Interop Part 2: C# Server Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645738%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: According to Sasha there are 2 more ways actually.

Comment: Yup, there's no requirement for the "decoupling" suggested. The ".Net" environment is basically mscoree.dll, and it can load in native processes.

Answer (score 12):

You can embed any CLR assembly (C#, VB.NET, F#, ...) in a native C++ program using what's called "[CLR Hosting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380850.aspx)". This is how native programs (such as SQL Server) support .NET code extensions. E.g. *SQL CLR* in SQL Server.

You load the CLR into a native process using [`CorBindToRuntimeEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/99sz37yh.aspx) for .NET 2.0 and [`CLRCreateInstance()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537633.aspx) in .NET 4.

Details can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380850.aspx), or Jeff Richter's book [*CLR via C#*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045).

Answer (score 9):

Sasha Goldshtein is the man for this stuff:

*There are again several ways to do it: 
1. Reverse P/Invoke (has to start from .NET delegate passed as callback, so this is only good if the "action" begins in your .NET code);
2. COM interop (every .NET class can also be a COM object, with or without explicit interfaces);
3. C++/CLI wrapper classes.*

See http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/02/16/net-to-c-bridge.aspx

See also :
http://www.gregcons.com/KateBlog/CallingManagedCodeFromNativeCode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to use C++/CLI. If you can't use that in your code, write a wrapper dll and call that dll.