# Call C# dll from unmanaged C++ app without COM

Tags: c#, c++, dll, com, unmanaged

Is there a way to call c# dll from c++ unmanaged application without COM usage?

Comment: You could always [embed Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono)...

Comment: can be done via mixed mode dlls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling C# code from C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778590/calling-c-sharp-code-from-c)

Comment: There are multiple techniques listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23182821/184528

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using `Reverse P/Invoke` - example and discussion [here](http://tigerang.blogspot.com/2008/09/reverse-pinvoke.html).

Comment: Thank you. That's interesting.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually possible to disassemble, modify the IL, and reassemble it with exported functions.  I messed with this a few years ago, and created an application that would disassemble a dll, provide a list of functions that could potentially be exported - allowing the user to select them, then re-write the IL and reassemble everything.  Then, I could call directly into the dll from unmanaged code...or p-invoke into the dll from managed code (not really practical, but interesting nonetheless).

Surely there is a reason that this isn't supported in the .net languages themselves (even tho it is supported in MSIL). I wouldn't use this in production:

Dead link:
<strike>http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/03/exporting-managed-code-as-unmanaged/</strike>

Wayback Machine:
https://web.archive.org/web/20140213030149/http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/03/exporting-managed-code-as-unmanaged/

Comment: It is supported in C++/CLI, it automatically creates a thunk that will load the CLR when you __declspec(dllexport) a static C++/CLI function.  Which is the Big Trick of course, can't run managed code without loading the CLR.

Comment: @Hans When you add exports to your IL, ILASM will do everything that is required for your assembly to be used as if it were a native one.

Answer (score 1):

I might be a bit late, but check [this](http://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) out.

Using this little msbuild task, you can create a C# library that can be called as if it were a native DLL. (e.g. write plugins for apps that require them to be native dlls)

Oh and don't forget to use the [project template](http://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/csharpprojecttemplateforunmanagedexports), which will setup everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option really is to either use C++.net or create a C++.net wrapper for it that exports what you need.

[Calling C# code from C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778590/calling-c-code-from-c)