# exposing C# methods to unmanaged

Tags: c#, .net, il

*that approach in "possible duplicate" is different to the one in the book. The book's approach is to extend a managed .dll after compilation through a decompile, recompile process. The approach that you think is an exact duplicate is actually a pre compilation technique. I prefer method in the book because it is more AOP in style. Thanks for the link though. I will also explore this avenue*

In *Expert .NET 2.0 IL Assembler*, in Ch 18 pp. 387 Serge Lidin talks about Creative Round-Tripping.  He says, "ILAsm allows you to export the managed methods as unmanaged
entry points".

I haven't heard this talked about anywhere else.  Is this something that you can do in PostSharp?  Are there any downloadable code / script examples of using this technique available?

To clarify, I don't want to use COM or Managed C++.  So what's the best way to implement a call to a C# method from C/C++ through thunking?

Comment: @PaulSasik: that approach is different to the one in the book.  The book's approach is to extend a managed .dll after compilation.   This approach is pre compilation.  I prefer method in the book because it is more AOP in style.  Thanks for the link though.  I will also explore this avenue.

Comment: The [bottom answer of that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4605486) links to [Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) which sounds like your citation.

Comment: @Rup: yes it is.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Pity there's no working downloadable example though.

Comment: @MarcGravel: do you think that closing the question was the right thing to do?

Comment: fine, give it another go, but: I suspect it was

Comment: @MarcGravell: ty.  I have some good leads to follow up on now, but maybe somebody will be able to fill in the blanks a little better.  I'm surprised that this technique hasn't had more exposure.  It appears to be really useful in some specific situations.

Comment: What do you mean about no working downloadable example? I've downloaded the code from Robert's site. Works well.

Comment: @DavidHefferman: was in the middle of something and typed before I looked thinking I knew entirely what was on that link from memory.  I didn't.  I downloaded that too.  It works well?  That's great.  Can't wait to give it a try.  Does the managed code also perform well?

Comment: Is anyone going to link the article as an answer and tell us if the sample code behaved as described?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: I now have it on good authority that the technique from https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports came from the book I mentioned.  It's working for people.  I haven't run extensive tests on it yet.  I will get back to the thread once I have.  IL manipulation is a valid technique.  It's the basis of the PostSharp product http://www.sharpcrafters.com/.  However Anders (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Hejlsberg) doesn't like the technique (changing IL).  Not sure what to say on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ildasm, change corflags, add v-table info and export function, ilasm and you're done.

Here's a code project article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37675/Simple-Method-of-DLL-Export-without-C-CLI

Which is based on:

Dead link:
<strike>http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/03/exporting-managed-code-as-unmanaged/</strike>

Wayback Machine for dead link:
https://web.archive.org/web/20140213030149/http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/03/exporting-managed-code-as-unmanaged/

Which is based on:
[http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Microsoft-NET-IL-Assembler/dp/0735615470](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735615470)  (the first edition of the book you refer to)