# C# Classes from javascript though Firebreath Framework

Tags: c#, javascript, c++-cli, firebreath

I have to call the C# classes from javascript through Firebreath Framework.
I am new to the [Firebreath Framework](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+Home).

Suppose In the C#,
    Public Class ImageDraw
    {
     }
    Public Class Test
    {
     public void TestDrawImage(ImageDraw imageDraw)
     {
       }
     }

Then I have to call this TestDrawImage(ImageDraw imageDraw) from javascript through  firebreath framework. 
The same way i have to call the events,properties ,classes of C# from javascript through Firebreath framework.. 
I want the generalized solution for this problem
How should i implement this?
If you have any solution, sort of information ,ways to communicate the C# classes from Javascript through Firebreath Framework then please let me know..

I already created the wrapper for the same.
But the problem is for each new method i have to instantiate the wrapper in the Firebreath.
Same might be happened for each new class from C# in Firebreath i have to instantiate the wrapper.
So Is it possible to have some centralized method that gathers the full instance of wrapper in Firebreath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FireBreath is C++, not C#. If you want to call C# functions from a firebreath plugin you'll have to create some sort of bridge between the firebreath c++ and the c# stuff. Learn how to do that, then learn enough C++ to tie it into your firebreath plugin.

Comment: Could you please suggest what kind of bridge i have to build between the firebreath C++ and the C# stuff

Comment: I sure can't.  I don't know.  Try asking (or searching for) a question about calling C# code from c++.  Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778590/calling-c-sharp-code-from-c or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465639/call-c-sharp-dll-from-unmanaged-c-app-without-com?lq=1.  Note that you probably can't build FireBreath with CLR on, so you will likely need to create an intermediate C++ DLL.