# Delegate to trigger C# function from referenced C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, dll, pinvoke

I have a working unmanaged C++ DLL which is attached to my C# code using p/invoke

```
    [DllImport("p2p.dll", EntryPoint = "Start")]
    public static extern void Start();

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Thread th= new Thread(Start);
         th.Start();
....
```

This way i can retrieve information from my C++ code, but if my C++ code needs to trigger a C# function then how do i do it in a smart way rather than putting all request in a queue and checking it from C# in a thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use Managed C++, or initialize your C++ library from C# by passing it a set of function pointers (delegates on the managed side) to all relevant entry points.

At the start of your program call the initializer:

```
[DllImport("p2p.dll")]
public static extern void Initialize(Action triggerManagedAction);

Initialize(() => {Console.WriteLine("called from C++");});
```

And in the C++ implementation of that function, remember the function pointer.

**Please also read the comment by Hans Passant and Google this technique before using it.** I is easy to introduce bugs here.

Comment: Thank, i cant use Managed C++, but can you elaborate more on what you said second regarding  function pointers

Comment: Sure. I added some sample code. You have to research the C++-side yourself because I' don't know enough about that aspect.

Comment: The code snippet is very dangerous and easily leads to a crash when the garbage collector destroys the delegate object.  It must be stored in a field to stay alive.  It is also best to declare the delegate type separately so that the calling convention can be specified explicitly.  The posted snippet requires __stdcall on the function pointer to work properly.

Comment: @HansPassant, I now refer to your very important comment from my answer. Btw, feel free to edit my post.

Comment: @usr onus is on you rather than Hans to fix the post

Comment: hey @usr my Initialize(()... says "Method must have a return type." Navin did you get this to work? thks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating a Managed C++ class, that acts as a proxy between your C++ and .Net event handlers. Here is how it looks:

- Suppose that you register notifications for the C++ class with, by publishing a, say, ICEventHandler interface, whose notify() method will be called.
- In managed C++ create a class, derived from ICEventHandler, that has a delegate, called for example Notify(). In the inherited ICEvenhHandler.notifty() call the Notify delegate.
- Having a .net Nofity method, construct an instance of your proxy class, and pass that for the C++ event source class

This way a C++ event will fire your .Net Notify method.

Comment: okay.., i guess the problem here will be when i implement the bridge between unmanaged and managed isnt it? because i cannot compile my code as managed, yes i can refence the unmanged to a managed C++, but isnt that a long process and the DLL is a network layer so wont it get slow down.

Comment: The managed c++ bridge can reference the C++ dll library, and will produce a .net assembly, that can be referenced from any .net project. We did this, and was not notably slow, however other interprocess communication means might be faster (Named Pipes, Sockets, etc.)

Comment: Thank you, Ill look in to it and let you know :)

Comment: I hope you mean C++/CLI, not "Managed Extensions for C++".

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways would be compiling your C++ code with a /clr flag. Couple different examples can be found in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778590/calling-c-sharp-code-from-c).

Comment: i am using boost/asio and boost/thread so i cannot compile it with /clr. Its possible to compile boost in /clr but in my case its kind of complex.