# How to call C# code in C++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, usb

I have a small C# class (Gram.cs) and it is working with a 3rd party dll to operate a device. Now, I need to call some functions in this C# class using C++.

How can I do it?

I am using MS Visual Studio 2010 professional edition.

Comment: There is a question similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778590/calling-c-sharp-code-from-c

Comment: Looking into your scenario don't you really need to call C++ function **from** the C# class?

Comment: @gustavodidomenico: no, C# from C++

Comment: @pmni: How can I add the C# file into the project?

Comment: If C# class is _small_, and it deals with native dll, it might by simpler rewrite that class in C++, then integrate .Net with your app.

Comment: @Lol4t0: agree. Please provide your comment as an answer

Answer (score 3):

If `C#` class is small, and it deals with native `dll`, it might by simpler rewrite that class in `C++`, rather then integrate `.Net` into your application. In addition, integrating `.Net` will force whole `.Net` virtual machine to start just for processing your simple class.

Otherwise,

- You could use *COM interop*: build an assembly based on your `C#` class and make it COM visible. Then you could use class as a COM-object.
- You can use *Managed C++* to make a wrapper between managed and unmanaged code.
- You can *reverse control flow*, so `C#` code will call unmanaged functions. In this case you can export it from your binary and import from `C#` code with `DllImport` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you should make your c# code as COM visible from your c# project settings and use c# IJW regasm tool.

Look into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173185.aspx

I had integrated c# into c++ using this approach few years ago.

You will be able to load your c# assembly as a COM component in your c++ code.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for (I've answered similiar question here before: [how to : use c++ projects for windows phone (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126017/how-to-use-c-projects-for-windows-phone-c/18128735#18128735))

a) Load symbols directly from C library, for example:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
static class win32
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);   
}
```

(this is taken from: http://www.andyrushton.co.uk/csharp-dynamic-loading-of-a-c-dll-at-run-time/ after brief googling)

You need to export the C++ interface methods as "C" for that, e.g.:

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) int MyFunc(long parm1);
```

(from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wf2w9f6x.aspx)

b) Use a wrapper in C++/CLI to connect unmanaged C++ to managed C#:

here's a good example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes

Do note that the syntax is somewhat weird at first look, and not eveything can be used. However, what you gain is ability to use the C++ classes - something that exporting "C" prohibits you from doing.

Comment: Isn't this the exact reverse of what the question asked?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou that's correct, since it was a while ago I'm not sure why I answered it like this. Quick look through the comments to the question suggests someone mentioned rewriting the C#-interface-y part in C++, the calling that from C#, so that might be it.