# Questions about Calling C# function from C++, Reversed P/Invoke on windows phone

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Currently I need to call a C# function from C++ code on windows phone,
I read a lot about P/Invoke, this thread might be a duplicate.....

But so far I didn't find a "complete" thread includes projects and hook up teaches me how to do this
Also there are tons of terminology confused me.
So I have to create this thread:

Q1. If I don't want to use COM, the tech I should use is called ?
   This tech requires me to create a C# dll, then I can call the function in the C# dll from C++ code, right?

---

--------On C# side:

Q2. Project wise
   I should place the function I want to call from C++ code in a C# DLL project.
   So the type of the project I created is 
   Is there anything else I need to manually setup on project side?

Q3. In the *.cs file, 
   Use deligate, all the reference use deligate.
   But some of reference use

```
[DllExport( "blah.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall) ]
```

Some of them not.
   Which confuses me.
   Is Dllexport must required for the dll function in *.cs?

---

--------On C++ side:

Q4. Project setting wise, People say, 
   I should use C++/CLI(Common Language Infrastructure)
   What confused me here is, is (CLI) a setting in project?
   How do I know my C++ project is CLI or not? or how do I set that?
   How do I know my C++ project is Managed or not? or how do I set that?

Actually I new/delete in the C++, so it should be machine code(unmanaged)
   But does the C++ project that calls C# function has to be managed?
   And does managed/unmanaged has something to do with CLI?

---

--------On both C#/C++ project side:

Q5  None of the tutorial tells me how to hook up the projects!

I did this by adding the  to the  like this:
   Common Properties->Add New Reference

But when try to call the C# function from C++,
   It tells me error, unsolved external.
   I tried put the function in a C# name space,
   then in C++, I write:

```
using namespace MyCSharpNamespace;
```

It gives me an error:

```
error C2871: 'MyCSharpNamespace' : a namespace with this name does not exist
```

If it's a C++ dll, I just need to include the C++ header file, then it's done.
   But what do I do with a *.cs file?

I'll really appreciate the answer from you guys.

Comment: You are not doing this correctly, add a new project and use the "Windows Runtime Component" project template.  Create a public ref class, you can directly call it from your C# code.  The language extension is called C++/CX, nothing to do with C++/CLI.

Comment: I didn't get it, "you can directly call it from your C# code"
But I want to call the C# function from C++.

Comment: It works just as well the other way around.  Events are also well supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I just realize some part of me is wrong,
I just know what is Reverse P/Invoke:

Reverse P/Invoke means:

Start the project in C#,
Create a C# delegate function.
Create a C++ dll.
Call a function in C# -> call a function in C++ -> call the C# delegation function.

This is how the function stack look like:

|-> C#  delegate function

|-> C++ dll function

|-> C#  main function

Is that correct?
So this is not calling a C# function from C++ ....
What do I do if I want to call a C# function from C++ ....
I mean, I want to start a C++ project, and call a C# function in that C++ project....

Comment: Several ways to do this; see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778590/calling-c-sharp-code-from-c. To do this from unadulterated, non-CLI C++ code, COM would probably be the preferred method, and to use COM you just have to mark the project as COM-visible in its AssemblyInfo.cs file and make sure your classes follow some basic visibility and structure rules.