# Calling managed code (C#/Visual Basic VS2010) from an unmanagened project (C/C++ VS2005)

Tags: c#, c++, unmanaged, managed

Short Version:

**Have:** DLL's Managed Code (C#/Visual Basic) from Brüel & Kjær SDK

**Need:** Communicate with the DLL's in our old Project Un-Managed Code (C++ Visual Studio 2005)

Long Version:

We have a project written in C/C++ (**Visual Studio 2005**). Now I have to implement a communication with a new device. (*Brüel & Kjær 2250SDK Noice*).

The problem is, *Brüel & Kjær* only supports you with Libraries for C# or Visual Basic (**Managed-Code**) (**Visual Studio 2010 and higher**), but our project is an old **unmanaged C/C++ code**.

So, the question is, how can I work with the DLL's in my old C++ Code?
I don't have the source of the DLL's, I only have the DLLs.

I hope someone out there can help me with that problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling C# code from C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778590/calling-c-sharp-code-from-c)

Comment: You need C++/CLI. However, I'd say you also need to ditch a 10year old IDE and use something more recent - I'm not even sure you're going to be able to use B&K's dlls with VS2005 but even if you are there should be no good reasons to stick with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is probably C++/CLI (Common Language Infrastructure). It basically enables you to use .NET types in C++. With this you could call a C# DLL and use the data which is provided by the DLL as the .NET type. Since you already have you application in C++ code, I guess you don't want to rewrite it completely. You'd than have to convert the managed types to unmanaged types, which is possible with C++/CLI.

If you want to know more about it, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-minutes) is a lengthy MSDN article about it and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-minutes) is a useful little quick tutorial.