# How to pass kinect data streams from one computer to another computer in C++

Tags: c++, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, kinect

I want to pass kinect data from one computer to another computer.I got the sample source from codeplex. It is a  C# application.So C# applications can directly use this library as it is.But i am coding in C++,how can i use the above code in c++ windows application.

[kinectservice](https://kinectservice.codeplex.com/)

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778590/calling-c-sharp-code-from-c  may help.

Comment: Use TCP sockets just as they do. I realized this using Qt TCP sockets.