# integrate C# into C++

Tags: c#, c++, twitter, openframeworks

I am using Tweetinvi in order to get information from twitter to use it with openFrameworks library and C++.

I am currently returning information to the console straight from twitter but I am unsure how I might get this information into my c++ program, is this usually done?

I had thoughts of maybe saving it to a text file and read that from C++, but hopefully there is a way to integrate the programs.

Thanks

Comment: You could use a Microsoft Visual C++ project alongside your C# project

Comment: Did you explore solutions from that post [Calling C# code from C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778590/calling-c-sharp-code-from-c) ?

Answer (score 0):

For openFrameworks you can't compile as /clr, which is the most straight forward solution. You will need to create a c++/cli wrapper that exposes the C#. [This](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Consuming-C-Library-in-937458e5) and [this](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/556582/usingplusc-23plusfromplusnativeplusc-2b-2bpluswith) are two guides that helped me do this.