# Using c# dll inside c++ solution

Tags: c#, c++

I know this is a wierd question but I need to use a dll created using c# in a c# file contained inside c++ project. Currently i tried adding reference from project in visual studio but still when writing c# code, i cant get the reference from dll. (Fyi, The c# file inside the project is compiled as .net module and is used in c++ files). Can someone help me regarding this. I only need to refer the dll inside my c# file contained in c++ project.

Thanks

Comment: Can you include your source code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/778590/2328447

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling C# code from C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778590/calling-c-sharp-code-from-c)