# How transferring an image to buffer in c++(dll) and then read/write in buffer in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, buffer

How transferring an image to buffer in c++(dll) and then read/write in buffer in C# and return to c++(dll) in real time? The process I'm looking is in the following :

1- First, I read an image form hard drive;
Mat inputImage = read(“/,…./Test.jpg”);

2- Put in the buffer:

imencode(".jpg", inputImage, inputBuff, paramBuffer);

3- send form c++ to c#
??? (I don’t  know).

4- read in c# from buffer
??? (I don’t  know).

5- write the changes that happens through c++ and c# in buffer
??? (I don’t  know).

I'm using Opencv c++.

I really thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778590/calling-c-sharp-code-from-c

Comment: Basically, you can use a C++/CLI assembly. In that assembly you can copy the unmanged image buffer to the managed counterpart. That managed buffer can be provided in a public managed class to the .NET world, in your case a second C# assembly that checks/manipulates the image buffer etc. C++/CLI is the fastest interop technology.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Runtime.InteropServices` in C# to call functions in external libraries, for example

**c++ code**

```
extern "c"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl Read(unsigned char*& buffer)
    {
        //allocate and write to buffer
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl Write(unsigned char* buffer)
    {
        //do something with the buffer
    }
}
```

and compile it into a dll

**C# code**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Main
{
    [DllImport(DLL_FILE, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void Read(out IntPtr buffer);

    [DllImport(DLL_FILE, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void Write(byte[] buffer);

    public static void ReadFromExtern()
    {
        IntPtr bufferPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        Read(bufferPtr);

        int length = LENGTH;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[length];        
        Marshal.Copy(bufferPtr, buffer, 0, length);
        //do something with buffer
    }

    public static void WriteToExtern(byte[] buffer)
    {
        Write(buffer);
        //or do something else
    }
}
```

Note:

1. If you used dynamically allocated memory in the c++ code, remember to also write a wrapper function to free it, otherwise causing memory leak.
2. `__declspec(dllexport)` is Windows specific to export functions to dll(s).
3. `extern "C"` is to avoid name mangling by c++ compilers, can be omitted if using c compilers
4. For string transferring, use `char*` in c++ and `System.Text.StringBuilder` in c#